# Looping over widgets in Tkinter

Tags: python, loops, widget, tkinter

here's the issue I'm thinking of:

I have a number of similar widgets in the frame(e.g. Lables). I update them every iteration of the algorithm (using `root.update()`  in the relevant function. What I'd like to know, is how to loop through each Label.

Of course, they were created with something like

```
self.var1=IntVar()
self.lab1=Label(frame,textvariable=self.var1)
self.lab1.grid()
```

So each of the lables are named lab1,lab2, etc. I'm quite sure there should either be a better way of naming them, so that I don't have to call each name explicitly, or somehow loop though them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to store references to each widget in a list or dictionary rather than (or in addition to) scaler instance variables.

Comment: you mean something like `list1=[self.var1,self.var2]` and then loop through `list1[list]`?

Comment: I know this is old, but it just saved me a ton of time.

Answer (score 14):

Your consistant name scheme let you use the variable name to iterate through your variables:

```
for i in range(1,n):
    label = getattr(self, "lab"+str(i))
```

You may also consider relying on Tkinter whom retain a tree structure of your widgets accessible through `children` widget attribute (a dictionary):

```
for child in frame.children.values():
    #do something to all children
```

And eventually add some filtering if your frame contains other widgets. For instance, to filter on classes of widgets:

```
for label in filter(lambda w:isinstance(w,Label), frame.children.itervalues()):
    #do something on labels
```

Note that children does not have any  guarantee on order traversal. For such service, you may rely on geometry manager infos, ie `pack_slaves` or `grid_slaves`:

```
for child in frame.pack_slaves():
    #traverse in pack addition order
#or
for child in reversed(frame.grid_slaves()):
    #traverse in grid addition order
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answers did not work exactly as I wanted them to, and so I have done this in Python 3.11 by recursively looking through all children of a window/frame:

```
def IterateWindowWidgets(window):
    for widget in window.winfo_children():
        lastDot = str(widget).rfind('.')
        # The format of str(widget) is '!window.!frame.!widget', so this is to only
        # look at the lowest current widget in the hierarchy.
        if '!toplevel' in str(widget)[lastDot:] or '!frame' in str(widget)[lastDot:]:
            IterateWindowWidgets(widget)
        else:
            if '!label' in str(widget)[lastDot:]
                widget.yourCommandHere
```