# Dividing by Zero while Generating List in Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, divide-by-zero

I am trying to make a list of percents generated by User-Input into the table. The table is working and has inputs from e1 - e24. The problem is that some of the inputs are zero, and thus my program stops when it runs into the error.

Here is the user input (generated by Tkinter):

[image]

The first column is e1-e12 and the second is e13-e24. Thus, I divide e1 by e13 to divide along the row.

Here is the list:

```
   Percents= [("%.2f" % (int(e1.get())/int(e13.get()))), ("%.2f" % (int(e2.get())/int(e14.get()))),\
   ("%.2f" % (int(e3.get())/int(e15.get()))),("%.2f" % (int(e4.get())/int(e16.get()))),\
   ("%.2f" % (int(e5.get())/int(e17.get()))),("%.2f" % (int(e6.get())/int(e18.get()))),\
   ("%.2f" % (int(e7.get())/int(e19.get()))),("%.2f" % (int(e8.get())/int(e20.get()))),\
   ("%.2f" % (int(e9.get())/int(e21.get()))),("%.2f" % (int(e10.get())/int(e22.get()))),\
   ("%.2f" % (int(e11.get())/int(e23.get()))),("%.2f" % (int(e12.get())/int(e24.get())))]
```

When it gets to the zeroes, though, it gets stuck. I tried `try:` and `except ZeroDivisionError:` but since it inevitably runs into the error it doesn't store anything from the Percent List. I was hoping to make the list by a loop but trying e(i) is different than e1 so I got roadblocked by that issue.

```
for i in range(1, 12):
    if 5 > i:
    Percents.append("%.2f" % (int(e(i).get())/int(e(i+12).get())))
```

EDIT: Based on an answer below, I attempted:

```
def calc_percent(foo,bar):   
   try:
       return ("%.2f" % (int(foo.get())/int(bar.get())))
   except ZeroDivisionError:
       return "0"

Percents = [calc_percent(e1,e13),calc_percent(e2,e14)]
print Percents
```

I get `TclError: invalid command name ".286005808"`
So I put `Percents` and `print Percents` inside the def and get `TypeError: calc_percent() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)`

Comment: " I was hoping to make the list by a loop but trying e(i) is different than e1 so I got roadblocked by that issue." You could create a list of entries. Then you could do `entries[i]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be a better idea to create 2 lists of entries (one for each column), then do:

```
my_list = [e_left.get() / e_right.get() for e_left, e_right in zip(left_entries_list, right_entries_list) if e_right.get() != 0 else y]
```

`y` is whatever value you decide to use in case the right value is `0`.

**EDIT:** Apparently you can use `if` in list comprehensions but `if...else` won't work. So you can use `map` instead. Here is a simplified example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [1, 1, 0, 1]

# -1 or other `default value` you wish to use
my_list = map(lambda x, y: x / y if y != 0 else -1, a, b)

print my_list
>> [1.0, 2.0, -1, 4.0]
```

Comment: You can't use `if ... else` as the guard in the list comprehension. You have a single value for the list, which will either be a generator or the value `y`.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you, this worked and was much simpler than my approach.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to solve this would be to create a function definition that does the calculation for you and then you can do the error handling in there.

```
def calc_percent(foo, bar):
    try:
        return "%.2f" % (int(foo)/int(bar))
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return "0" # or whatever you wanted to return
```

and then call it in your percents definition.

```
percents = [calc_percent(e1.get(),e13.get()),....
```

you may also want to check out this post for doing what you actually suggested: [Looping over widgets in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751434/looping-over-widgets-in-tkinter)

Comment: I'd just pass `e1` et al. as arguments, and call `get` inside `calc_percent`.

Comment: I attempted this method and got some errors. Put it in an edit in the original post.

Answer (score -1):

One way is to prepopulate with zeroes:
Percents = [0]*12
Then, insert where you can:

```
try:
    Percents[x] = #stuff
...
```