# Tkinter windows configurtion is not working

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter

I'm trying to configure the grid of all winsows inside a Tkinter().

For exemple:

```
import tkinter as Tk

window = Tk()
window.state('zoomed')
window.rowconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform='a')
winsdow.columnconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform='a')

window_home = Frame(window)
window_documents = Frame(window)
window_form = Frame(window)
```

This is the basic structure of my code. All I want to do is to configure the frames window_home, window_documents and window_form using a for loop, as below:

```
for frame in window:
  frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform='a')
  frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform='a')
```

but the word 'in', after 'for frame', is not looking activate in vscode. It looks like i'm doing something syntactically wrong, but I don't know what.

Can someonw smarter than me (not rare at all) help with this issue?

I don't even know what to try. The IDE just doesn't tell me what is wrong with the code.

Comment: what happens when you run the code? does it give you an error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Looping over widgets in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751434/looping-over-widgets-in-tkinter)

Comment: If the code in your IDE is formatted the same as above, you need to indent the lines after the "for frame in window:" line

Comment: Your code raises exception on the line `window = Tk()` because `Tk` is a module alias.

Comment: @DawsonBeatty It doesn't give any error. It just do not aply the configuration.

Comment: @Jan_B I don't think so. The problem the user in this topic is facing is diferent from the one I'm trying to solve...

Comment: To expand on @acw1668's comment: as-written the alias `Tk` is shadowing tkinter's `Tk` class, which is very likely *not* what you want. Most often you'll see `import tkinter as tk` (case is important!!), then you'll instantiate tkinter with something akin to `window = tk.Tk()`. FWIW, you can use any alias you want, e.g. `import tkinter as foo` and `window = foo.Tk()`, but using the alias `tk` is conventional.

Comment: There are several problems with this code, as mentioned by other commenters. After you fix all of those errors, the problem is likely that the IDE thinks that `window` is not iterable, because it's not. `window` is an object, not something list-like.

Comment: To loop over a list of frames inside some other window you need to do something like `for frame in window.winfo_children()`.

Comment: @DawsonBeatty The code is properly formatted in my IDE. I just forgot to indent it here. But I've edited the post to solve it.

Comment: @BryanOakley I believe it worked! I just don't understand why I have to insert this .winfo_children() in window when I have another for loop for another windows that are inside the fist one and I didn't need to specify them as I needed to do in window...

Comment: @Tarenta: the explanation is likely that those two different blocks of code are indeed different even though you think they are similar. `window` is a window object rather than a list, and you can't loop over a window object. `window.winfo_children()` is a function call that returns a list.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to change line 3 to `window = tk.Tk()`, and I made the import lowercase because it is a better naming convention.

Secondly, for the window to show you must call `window.mainloop()` at the end of the code.

Thirdly, `window` is not iterable, it is a tk.Tk class, so you can't iterate through it using a `for` loop. Since there are only 3 frames, I wouldn't bother using any sort of iteration and would just do the following:

```py
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.state('normal')
window.rowconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform='a')
window.columnconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform='a')

window_home = tk.Frame(window)
window_home.rowconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform='a')
window_home.columnconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform='a')

window_documents = tk.Frame(window)
window_documents.rowconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform='a')
window_documents.columnconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform='a')

window_form = tk.Frame(window)
window_form.rowconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform='a')
window_form.columnconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform='a')

window.mainloop()
```

If you insist on using a `for` loop you can do the following:

```py
frames = [window_home, window_documents, window_form]
for frame in frames:
    frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform='a')
    frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform='a')
```